# How do I reset an extent of a layer to default?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

My map has multiple regions. If a certain region is selected I restrict all avalaible layers to an extent of a selected region by setting "extent" property like so: `allLayers.forEach(l => l.setExtent(extent))`. Whenever I unselect a region I want to see the whole map again. How do I reset the extent of the layers whose extent I changed before?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. `allLayers.forEach(l => l.setExtent(undefined)).` Had to pass undefined so typescript doesn't yell at me, empty braces are supposed to work too.